# Tips for creating a link for 3d models when clicked on

Tags: 3d, aframe

Any tips for creating 3d models that link to other urls when clicked on?

In more detail, I have loaded a 3d model into one of my scenes and would like to have the model link to another url when clicked on.

I am preloading the model assets as such:

```
<a-assets>

<a-asset-item id="foo-obj" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/62d6d539-d638-4686-ba78-f926cc1d10a8%2FPortal_FInal.obj?1544456633029"></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="foo-mtl"  src="assets/models/Portal_FInal2.mtl"></a-asset-item>  
</a-assets>
```

and then calling the the model into the scene as such:

```
<a-obj-model id="link" src="#foo-obj" mtl="#foo-mtl"  position="3 -3 -11" rotation="0 45 0"> ></a-obj-model>
```

I have tried adding an href property to the object to no avail. I was able to get the camera and cursor into the scene. But I have not gotten the cursor to recognize the link. Any recommendations?

Comment: Share full code with camera and cursor. Glitch.io is a good option.

Comment: Let me know if you have any trouble viewing. As a work around - I have been trying to use entity component from aframe’s 360 image galleries example to position in front of the 3d model and use as a mask that triggers sky component animation.

Not sure if this is the most robust solution. But I think the quickest fix for now.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ambitious-accelerator?path=README.md:1:0

Comment: FWIW, the raycaster selector is not correct. You have `id=“link”` and should be `class=“link”`

Comment: Also notice you have elements with same id. It should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a [link](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/link.html) component, it creates a 'portal - like' geometry. If you just want your model to redirect to another page, you can write a really simple component, using the `link`s [source code](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/link.js#L160-L162):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('redirect', {
  schema {
    href: {default: ''}
  },
  init() {
     // react to the click
     this.el.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
       // navigate to another url
       window.location = this.data.href
     })
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
<a-obj-model redirect="href: google.com"></a-obj-model>
```

Comment: A-Frame implements the logic for in-VR navigation. No extra code to necessary to handle it. Firefox, Samsung Internet, Oculus Browser and Supermedium are the only browsers that fire the necessary events for VR browser at the moment.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos i understand that the part about "rules" was unnecessary then, is the rest the best way to go, if you want the simple case of a typical link ?

Comment: Never seen that proverb, awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

**Now, let's say you have 'n' (more than one) assets:**

```
<a-assets>

<a-asset-item id="foo1-obj" crossorigin="anonymous" src="whatever"></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="foo1-mtl"  src="whatever"></a-asset-item>

<a-asset-item id="foo2-obj" crossorigin="anonymous" src="whatever1"></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="foo1-mtl"  src="whatever2"></a-asset-item>

...

<a-asset-item id="foon-obj" crossorigin="anonymous" src="whatevern"></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="foon-mtl"  src="whatevern"></a-asset-item>

</a-assets>
```

**And therefore 'n' a-obj-model(s):**

```
<a-obj-model redirect="href: example1.com"></a-obj-model>
<a-obj-model redirect="href: example2.com"></a-obj-model>

...

<a-obj-model redirect="href: examplen.com"></a-obj-model>
```

Doing as formerly proposed will open example1.com no matter which a-obj-model you click on.

i.e:

Clicking on the a-obj-model with the following redirect content: "href: example3.com" will redirect to example1.com and not the expected example3.com

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test</title>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.3/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component/master/dist/aframe-mouse-cursor-component.min.js"></script>    
  </head>

<script>

    AFRAME.registerComponent('redirect', {

      schema: {
        href: {default: ''}
      },

      init() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;  // <a-box>

         // react to the click
         this.el.addEventListener('click', function () {
           // navigate to another url
           window.location = data.href;
         })
      }
    });

</script>  

<body>

<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">

    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="background-obj" src="3Dmodel-background.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="background-mtl" src="3Dmodel.mtl"></a-asset-item>

        <a-asset-item id="wb-1-obj" src="3Dmodel-wb-1.obj"></a-asset-item>              
        <a-asset-item id="wb-2-obj" src="3Dmodel-wb-2.obj"></a-asset-item>              
        <a-asset-item id="wb-3-obj" src="3Dmodel-wb-3.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="wb-4-obj" src="3Dmodel-wb-4.obj"></a-asset-item>              
        <a-asset-item id="wb-6-obj" src="3Dmodel-wb-6.obj"></a-asset-item>              
    </a-assets>

    <a-entity raycaster="objects:.landscape,.environmentGround,.environmentDressing; far:0.5;"> 

    <a-camera
        position="-0.5 2 5"
        scale="2 2 2"
        wasd-controls-enabled="true"        
        wasd-controls="acceleration: 175; fly: true"
        look-controls-enabled="true"
        look-controls="reverseTouchDrag: true; reverseMouseDrag: false"
    >
    </a-camera>

    <a-obj-model
        obj-model="obj: #background-obj; mtl: #background-mtl"
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model
        redirect="href: example1.com"
        obj-model="obj: #wb-1-obj; mtl: #background-mtl"
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model
        redirect="href: example2.com"
        obj-model="obj: #wb-2-obj; mtl: #background-mtl"
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model
        redirect="href: example3.com"
        obj-model="obj: #wb-3-obj; mtl: #background-mtl"
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model
        redirect="href: example4.com"
        obj-model="obj: #wb-4-obj; mtl: #background-mtl"
    </a-obj-model>

    <a-obj-model
        redirect="href: example6.com"
        obj-model="obj: #wb-6-obj; mtl: #background-mtl"
    </a-obj-model>  

<a-sky color="#17191b"></a-sky>

</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, any hint on how to make it open the correct URL?